# How to get already booked customers in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abe27/2

```
CREATE TABLE members
    (`id` int, `memberName` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO members
    (`id`, `memberName`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Steve'),
    (2, 'John'),
    (3, 'Alex')
;

CREATE TABLE enquiry
    (`id` int, `memberId` int, `enq_status` varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO enquiry
    (`id`, `memberId`, `enq_status`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Cancelled'),
    (2, 1, 'Booked'),
    (3, 3, 'Booked'),
    (4, 2, 'Cancelled'),
    (5, 3, 'Booked'),
    (6, 3, ''),
    (7, 2, ''),
    (8, 1, '')    
;

CREATE TABLE bookings
    (`id` int, `enquiryId` int)
;

INSERT INTO bookings
    (`id`, `enquiryId`)
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 5)
;
```

My Query below:

```
SELECT m.memberName, e.id, e.enq_status 
FROM enquiry e,members m 
WHERE e.memberId = m.id AND e.enq_status = '';
```

In which I have `members`, `enquiry` and `bookings` table. In my query shown in SQLFiddle, I am retrieving the enquiries which are not cancelled or booked.

But I want to highlight or maybe add a column which will tell us that the customer who made the enquiry have already booked previously or not.

What could be the solution for it based on the above Fiddle, please advise!

Comment: OK, but I though fiddle will help quickly, will check and see how I can paste the whole code here.

Comment: OK, thanks, in the past, people asked for fiddle, so I thought it would be quicker. No prob, added code as well.

Comment: Actually fiddle helps a lot to be able to reproduce the situation you have, but inlining into the question is also important to understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use some tables more than once, and also you have to use `LEFT JOIN` for conditionally join the previous possible bookings.

```
SELECT e.id, m.memberName, e.enq_status, COUNT(b.id) as booking_count
FROM enquiry e
JOIN members m ON (e.memberId = m.id)
LEFT JOIN enquiry e2 ON (e2.memberId = m.id)
LEFT JOIN bookings b on (b.enquiryId=e2.id)
WHERE e.enq_status = ''
GROUP BY e.id
order by booking_count desc;
```

- Start with enquiries that are pending (`enq_status=''`)
- Get member data for that (that always exists, so use simple `JOIN`)
- Get possible enquiries for the members (POSSIBLE -> `LEFT JOIN`)
- Get possible bookings for those possible enquiries (`LEFT JOIN` again)
- Then, count the number of bookings found, for each (original) enquiry (`GROUP BY`)
- Also, order by the count

I think this is what you want. 
Instead of counting (`COUNT(b.id)`), you can use any other metrics, e.g `SUM(b.amount)` for using the total amount as ordering factor, or `COUNT(b.id)*10 + SUM(b.amount)` which is a combination of order count and total amount, etc.

Comment: this is returning all the enquiry, but i need all enquries only where status is blank, but want to know if that customer has booked earlier or not.

Comment: I assume that the customer first enquires (record in `enquiry`), then books (record in `bookings`). What phase do you want to know this information: before enquiry (no record saved) or after enquiry (record already saved)?

Comment: BTW, updated the query to contain a `WHERE e.enq_status = ''` line that filters those with empty status - that was very trivial.

Comment: No, I think it is still return wring results. The query I had written returning the enquiries, and in the bookings table we only have enquiry entries which are not cancelled, cancelled ones don't go in it. We want to give preference to customers who booked in the past, and for that we need a column in the query, true false etc. So, we need a list of enquiries with a column there with true/false, if the customer who enquired have booked earlier. Cancelled

Comment: could you please check and advise if anything can be done for the details I provided in my last comment?

Comment: Updated (an hour ago).

Comment: sorry I was testing it with my actually query and it looks to be working all ok. Was about to update here today. Thanks for all your help!